# How to locate the module that handles DNS resolving in buildroot?

Tags: dns, buildroot, resolv.conf

I have 2 different Linux devices, one's kernel is done using ltib (**L** from now on), and the other's by buildroot (**B** from now on).

I manage to add a DNS resolver to **B**  by using:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

and then `ping google.com` works fine.

On the other hand, on **L**, the same schtik didn't work, and although pinging ***8.8.8.8*** is ok, pinging ***google, google.com*** or ***www.google.com*** always fails.

What I want to do is somehow compare the 2 kernels to understand what is it inside **B** that is missing from **L** and enables the DNS resolving.

Where and what should I look for?

I've used [this guide](https://zwischenzugs.com/2018/06/08/anatomy-of-a-linux-dns-lookup-part-i/) and from it I understand that since my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` looks like this:

```
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
    passwd:     files  rf
    shadow:     files
    group:      files
    hosts:      files  dns
    services:   files
    networks:   files
    protocols:  files
    rpc:        files
    ethers:     files
    netmasks:   files
    netgroup:   files
    automount:  files
    aliases:    files
    bootparams:  [NOTFOUND=return] files
```

then the ping command should look at `/etc/resolv.conf` which includes the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

so I really don't see why my ping fails.

*I tried editing the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to remove the `files` from the `hosts` entry (made it look like `hosts:       dns`) but it didn't help.*

Answer (score 2):

It is not the Linux kernel that does DNS resolution, but the C library. Which C library is your LTIB system using ? By default, Buildroot is using uClibc, which doesn't have an `nssswitch.conf` configuration file.